# Unable to configure locking / transaction attributes

Tags: xml, infinispan, distributed-caching

Im trying to configure a infinispan 7.0.0 cluster with distributed caches and some detailed configuration.

From the Config details in http://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/7.0/configdocs/infinispan-config-7.0.html

you can see that its possible to have a distributed cache with locking PESSIMISTIC and set for example acquire-timeout in locking options.

I want to do this in the xml file. The thing is i can only find examples of distributed cache xml where its only like this :

```
 <distributed-cache name="distributedCache" mode="SYNC" owners="3" l1-lifespan="600000" />
```

and no further details configured. For replicated cache i can find configs like this:

```
<replicated-cache name="the-default-cache" statistics="true" mode="SYNC" remote-timeout="20000">
      <locking isolation="READ_COMMITTED"
         acquire-timeout="20000"
         write-skew="false"
         concurrency-level="5000"
         striping="false"
      />
      <transaction
            transaction-manager-lookup="org.infinispan.transaction.lookup.GenericTransactionManagerLookup"
            stop-timeout="30000"
            auto-commit="true"
            locking="OPTIMISTIC"
            mode="FULL_XA"
            />

   </replicated-cache>
```

if i do the same with distributed cache im getting a parsing error :

```
Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheConfigurationException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[24,4]
Message: Unexpected element '{urn:infinispan:config:7.0}locking' encountered
```

why am i not allowed to configure locking in distributed cache?! Am i missing something here? From the schema it also looks to me like this is allowed:

http://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/schemas/infinispan-config-7.0.xsd

Any help would really be appreciated im not an xml expert and maybe im just misunderstanding the schema or the user guide?

Comment: Post full config file you're trying to use.

Comment: My guess is that you forgot a `/>` at the end of the `<distributed-cache` line. Would definitely need to see the XML generating the error though, the example XML fragments that work aren't very relevant.